# Calling ASP-Actions by WWW::Mechanize (PERL)

Tags: asp.net, perl, www-mechanize

i need to parse through a list generated by an ASP action (LoadDialog) and i have no clue how to get it done. If I execute the following i simply get an empty HTML file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
#
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $url = "http://MYURL/LOGIN";
my $appurl = "http://MYURL/SOME.asp"; 

#SOME.asp calls http://MYURL/SOME.asp?Action=LoadDialog" to get results

my $username = 'username';
my $password = 'password';

#login to site 
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_name('login');
$mech->field(UserName => $username);
$mech->field(Password => $password);
$mech->click();

# get results from LoadDialog (?!)
$mech->get($appurl);
my $app_content = $mech->content();
print "$app_content\n";
```

Firebug tells me that `?Action=LoadDialog` is getting called by the mentioned URL, but Mechanize doesnt realize it (guessing).

Simply chaning `$myappurl` to `http://MYURL/SOME.asp?Action=LoadDialog` gives me an empty HTML file as well.

Is there any chance to get the ASP generated content? I cant use any other Perl modules which "run a browser", I need to find a solution usable in a shell.

Thanks in Advance,
Marley

Comment: What's the Web site? If you do not tell, then you have to figure out all the JS-based interaction with FireBug and the advice from [WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript) alone by yourself.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I was already reading about JavaScript is not supported, but I still need to get this to work :(!

Comment: Not a problem, all you need to do is to enable us to help you. Instead of `http://MYURL/SOME`, write the *real* Web site so we, too, can see how it works.

Comment: Hey daxim, my problem is that i actually cant post my URL because its part of an intranet and not available via web. Its about an Open Text (former RedDot) Content Management Server.